# Google +1 button causes JavaScript error

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-plus-one

We've recently started using the Google +1 button on our page, but whenever we include the Google script block this JavaScript error comes up in IE8:

> "No relay set (used as
>   window.postMessage targetOrigin),
>   cannot send cross-domain message"

This is a weird one, can't find out much about it. Does anyone have any clue what it means? I've tried moving the script include to the top of the page, but it doesn't help.

Comment: There is some ongoing help from a Google employee about this on this thread: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=44cbd1c65c0cd9e4&hl=en

Comment: The solution Andy Wan is suggesting [here][1] is working in IE7+8+9.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8133595/2173587

Comment: Thanks Jo, that's useful..

Answer (score 2):

Google +1 currently does not work on any version of IE.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Jrod - surely it's supposed to work on IE8 at least? I guess this means there's a general issue they're still working on. For anybody else interested in this problem, try Googling "google +1 ie8".